# Using pathPrefix for more specific path

Tags: android, url, path

I have to tackle two different URLs using my app:

```
1. *example.com/play/email
2. *example.com/n/?play%2Femail..... (long url)
```

The problem is that my app already has an intent filter for `*example.com/n/` in this way:

```
<data
  android:scheme="https"
  android:host="m.example.com"
  android:pathPrefix="/n/"/>
```

I have my own intent filter like this to tackle case 1:

```
<data
  android:host="*example.com"
  android:pathPrefix="/play/email"
  android:scheme="https" >
</data>
```

The problem is how do I tackle the case 2 (and open my own activity) without changing the intent filter already present in my app for the pathPrefix /n/?

Thus, case 2 as of now is being taken up by the intent filter already present, but I want to tackle it by my own intent filter (without changing the one already present)

How can I achieve this?